# QR Scanner works only on iPhone, not iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I grabbed some very nice source code for a QR scanner to read URLs from this gentleman (http://iphonenativeapp.blogspot.ca/2011/07/qr-code-readerscanner-for-iphone-app-in.html) in hopes to integrate it to an iPad app I am working on. However, when I attempt to run the QR scanner on an iPad, the program outputs this error:

> 2012-05-09 17:16:55.046 QRscanner[1176:10703] UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device.
>
> 2012-05-09 17:16:55.049 QRscanner[1176:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is amiss.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is amiss.

Seriously?

The error tells you that on iPad, `UIImagePickerController` must be presented via `UIPopoverController`.  So do that.  If you would care to look at [the documentation for `UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) you will not only see that it tells you this, but that it links to a description of how to use a `UIPopoverController`.

This is just about the most straightforward type of problem you will ever have in programming.  The system is specifically telling you what you must do, and the obvious part of the documentation tells you how to do it.

Comment: I attempted this solution. It did not work. That is why I am here, my good man.

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"?  Does it give the same error message?

Comment: @user1385816 We cannot read minds. Please show us the code you are using.